# How to have posts show up on a different page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I have in my `index.php` file and `page-readinglist.php` file. The wordpress page is selected to use the readinglist template and it does work with a simple `<p> example </p>`, but the posts don't show up.

```
    <div id="content">          
        <?php
            if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article class="post">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </article>

                <?php endwhile;

                else :
                    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

                endif;
        ?>
    </div>
```

I'm guessing I need some code in the `functions.php` file?

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'article') );

    return $query;
}
```

Is this something I modify to include the page ID of the page using the readinglist template? I'm having trouble setting up a page that doesn't use the `index.php` file.